# Пагинация в битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Всем привет.

Есть ИБ элементов. Содержит двухуровневые разделы. 10 разделов верхнего уровня и в каждом из них около 15 вложенных подразделов.
Необходимо сделать выборку таким образом чтобы была разбивка элементов по верхнему разделу. Т.е. -  раздел 1 и вывести список всех элементов включая все вложенные подразделы, раздел 2 - и т.д.

Сейчас у меня это сделано так:

```
   $arFilter2 = Array('IBLOCK_ID'=>9, 'ACTIVE'=>'Y', "DEPTH_LEVEL" => "1");
   $db_list2 = CIBlockSection::GetList(Array("ID"=>"ASC"), $arFilter2, true);
   while($ar_result2 = $db_list2->GetNext())
   {
      $arFilter = Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>9, "SECTION_ID"=>$ar_result2['ID'], "INCLUDE_SUBSECTIONS" => "Y", "CREATED_BY"=>$_REQUEST["userid"], "ACTIVE"=>"Y");
      $res = CIBlockElement::GetList(Array(), $arFilter, false, Array("nPageSize"=>250), Array());
      while($ob = $res->GetNextElement())
      {
         $arFields = $ob->GetFields();
         echo $arFields['NAME'].'<br>';
         //print_r($arFields);
      }
      echo '<br><br>';
   }
```

Т.е. получаю список верхних разделов, и затем по ID раздела делаю еще один GetList элементов с фильтром по разделу.
Все нормально, если общий список элементов небольшой. Но в некоторых случаях на странице отображается 70-80 и даже больше 100 элементов. Естественно встал вопрос пагинации.

Подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на класс CDBResult:
http://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_help/main/reference/cdbresult/navstart.php

Answer (score 0):

Читаем внимательно описание параметров метода `CIBlockElement::GetList`. Параметр `nPageSize` отвечает за колчисество элементов на страницу. Вы выставили значение в 250 и естественно Вам выдается много значений. Уменьшите значение и выводите компонент постраничной навигации. Для удобства если речь идет о выводе новостей, то можно реализовать с помощью компонента `news.list`, модифицировав `result_modifier.php` для перебора разделов. Или же если такой вариант тяжело осилить, то цикл перебора элементов компонента `news.list` разместите внутри цикла обхода разделов, не забыв добавить проверку поля элемента содержащего ID раздела с разделом который в данный момент обрабатывается циклом. В настройках включите отображение компонента постраничной навигации.

Для разделов с единичной вложенностью структура вывода выглядит как-то так, но лучше делать через `result_modifier`:

```
<?php
    $arOrder = array('SORT' => 'ASC');
    $arFilter = array('ACTIVE' => 'Y', 'IBLOCK_ID' => #IBLOCK_ID#);
    $arSelect = array('ID', 'NAME');
    $rsSection = CIBlockSection::GetList($arOrder, $arFilter, false, $arSelect, false);
?>    
<? while ($arSection = $rsSection->GetNext()) : ?>    
    <span><?= $arSection['NAME'] ?></span>    
        <? foreach($arResult['ITEMS'] as $arItem): ?>
            <?
            $this->AddEditAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['EDIT_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_EDIT"));
            $this->AddDeleteAction($arItem['ID'], $arItem['DELETE_LINK'], CIBlock::GetArrayByID($arItem["IBLOCK_ID"], "ELEMENT_DELETE"), array("CONFIRM" => GetMessage('CT_BNL_ELEMENT_DELETE_CONFIRM')));
            ?>
            <?= $arItem['NAME'] ?>
        <? endforeach; ?>
<? endwhile; ?>
<?if($arParams["DISPLAY_BOTTOM_PAGER"]):?>
    <br /><?=$arResult["NAV_STRING"]?>
<?endif;?>
```